# Windows fail to boot

Tags: boot, windows-xp

When I switch on my PC (no matter I chose normal start, safe mode or using last successful login setting), the Windows loading screen appeared and then after a few seconds the PC switches off (hence, no error message shown on screen).

I am guessing this is a hardware failure. May I ask which component could be the cause? e.g. HDD, RAM, CPU etc. ?

If not hardware related, can anyone please suggest what could be the issue?

Comment: Hello @xcoder, if any of those hardware had a problem, the BIOS POST test would not pass and the windows logo would never show up

Comment: @TechGeek thanks, in that case are you suggesting the issue is not with the hardware?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @xcoder the issue is not the hardware as the BIOS makes sure all the critical hardware needed for a functioning computer are up and runnin, if the windows logo shows up then that means RAM, CPU and HDD are fine and working

Comment: Could be an issue where the motherboard detects overheating and auto shuts down

Answer (score 2):

Software error is usually more likely than hardware. But as the post is
about Windows XP, I would assume that the computer in question is old
and a hardware error is very possible.

I would suggest to backup first your data using a Linux Live USB.
If that fails to boot, then the problem is hardware.

If Linux boots fine, then the most you can do is reinstall Windows XP
using a boot media of the same service-pack level as your installation.
If the installation boot does not detect the existing XP installation
on the disk, then there is a problem with the disk.

In any case, and depending on the age of the computer, you might need
to evaluate whether further investment in it is justified.